# XCEED wpf DataGrid Autofilter popup - Disable or hook closing event

Tags: wpf, popup, autofilter, xceed-datagrid, xceed

I am using exceed wpf grid (version 3.6.10159.15470) and I need either disable auto filter for a column or hook the closing (or closed) event. I searched the API and was not able to found how to achive any of these tasks. Can you help me?

Comment: Your best bet would be taking help from XCEED forum. StackOverflow may not be a place of proactive experts on 3rd party WPF controls.

Comment: Last week I posted this question there... no answer yet :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XAML, you can set the AllowAutoFilter property on the Column to false to disable the AutoFilter for that Column. If you want to set it in code, you can do so like this:

```
this.MyDataGridControl.Columns["Column1"].AllowAutoFilter = false;
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: What a shame! I did not see this property! Thank you.

Comment: Its ok... we all do that once in a while. How do you find the DataGridControl in your application?